# Select files which name starts with some text

Tags: php, file

How to select a list of files which name is starting with "sometext_". I have tried reading all files and checking their names with string function. Is there any better way to  do this?

Answer is :

```
$files = glob("files/sometext_*.txt");
print_r($files);
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read guide how to ask questions before posting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [glob](https://www.php.net/glob) function and see example in documentation

Just changed the example in documentation as your need

Here is the code

```
foreach (glob("sometext_*") as $filename) {
    echo "$filename size " . filesize($filename) . "\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to try now.